# Verifying a domain for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-cloud-platform

We're having trouble verifying our domain for our Google App Engine application.

We have a domain registered with Hostek, where our name servers are currently:

```
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com
```

I created a DNS zone in Google Cloud and added the TXT record with the value given to me by Google App Engine, but when click "Verify" on the Google side, I get the error

```
Verification failed for cbcdashboard.com using the DNS TXT record method (less than a minute ago). We couldn't find the verification token in your domain's TXT records. You might need to wait a few minutes before Google sees your changes to the TXT records.
```

Below that, if I click "Show found DNS TXT records", I see

```
google-site-verification=<the token I was given>
```

It seems to see the value, but to not think it's correct. I tried adding it with and without quotes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a dig and got this:

`"google-site-verification=PDmOnhweMP0C1aXpkNh-4kG-Mlhg3o22viWjGm_gn3U"`

So it seems like that it's a propagation issue. When you make changes to DNS it does not spread out on the DNS for a while. If you try again to verify does it now work?