# Subdomain validation with DNS-TXT-record fails

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-search-console

I need to add a subdomain to Google App Engine. Looking at domains and subdomains, which are offered in my App Engine I realize, that only validation with DNS-TXT-record will work (the list of offered domains and subdomains doesn't contain protocol).

I added a DNS-TXT record to the subdomain `measurement.mediaworx.com`. Trying to validate it I get an error:

[image]

where the founded record is exactly those I copied from the validation screen:

[image]

What I tried:

- To add a second TXT record - DNS validation fails,
- To create for this subdomain A and CNAME records, exactly as other validated domains and subdomains have - DNS validation fails,
- To delete all DNS records of this subdomain and add them next day - DNS validation fails,
- To validate this subdomain with attached protocols, as  **https**://`measurement.mediaworx.com` and **http**://`measurement.mediaworx.com`, with HTML file - validation of protocol+subdomain succeeded, but the subdomain in App Engine can't contain protocol - and DNS validation still fails.

In fact I still need to validate the subdomain without protocol with DNS-TXT record - and fail on it. Does somebody have an idea what to do in such case?

Comment: The error may be related to propagation issue as suggested in the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224451/verifying-a-domain-for-google-app-engine).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right, but I thought you just validated a domain and could then use whatever subdomain you wanted afterwards.